# Conditional update on two columns on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` dataframe where I'm trying to append two column values if the value of the second column is not `NaN`. Importantly, after appending the two values I need the value from the second column set to `NaN`. I have managed to concatenate the values but cannot update the second column to `NaN`.

This is what I start with for `ldc_df[['ad_StreetNo', 'ad_StreetNo2']].head(5)`:

```
ad_StreetNo ad_StreetNo2
0   284     NaN
1   51      NaN
2   136     NaN
3   196     198
4   227     NaN
```

This is what I currently have after appending:

```
ad_StreetNo ad_StreetNo2
0   284     NaN
1   51      NaN
2   136     NaN
3   196-198 198
4   227     NaN
```

But here is what I am trying to obtain:

```
ad_StreetNo ad_StreetNo2
0   284     NaN
1   51      NaN
2   136     NaN
3   196-198 NaN
4   227     NaN
```

Where the value for `ldc_df['ad_StreetNo2'].loc[3]` should be changed to `NaN`.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
def street_check(street_number_one, street_number_two):

    if pd.notnull(street_number_one) and pd.notnull(street_number_two):

        return str(street_number_one) + '-' + str(street_number_two)

    else:

        return street_number_one

ldc_df['ad_StreetNo'] = ldc_df[['ad_StreetNo', 'ad_StreetNo2']].apply(lambda x: street_check(*x),axis=1)
```

Does anyone have any advice as to how I can obtain my expected output?

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Convert the Street numbers to a string so that you can append the '-' character.
ldc_df['ad_StreetNo'] = ldc_df['ad_StreetNo'].astype(str)

# Create a mask of those addresses having an additional street number.
mask = ldc_df.loc[ldc_df['ad_StreetNo2'].notnull()

# Use the mask to append the additional street number.
ldc_df.loc[mask, 'ad_StreetNo'] += '-' + ldc_df.loc[mask, 'ad_StreetNo2'].astype(str)

# Set the additional street number to NaN.
ldc_df.loc[mask, 'ad_StreetNo2'] = np.nan
```

**Alternative Solution**

```
ldc_df['ad_StreetNo'] = (
    ldc_df['ad_StreetNo'].astype(str) 
    + ['' if np.isnan(n) else '-{}'.format(str(int(n))) 
       for n in ldc_df['ad_StreetNo2']]
)
ldc_df['ad_StreetNo2'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

`pd.DataFrame.stack` folds a dataframe with a single level column index into a series object.  Along the way, it drops any null values by default.  We can then group by the previous index levels and join with `'-'`.

```
df.stack().astype(str).groupby(level=0).apply('-'.join)

0        284
1         51
2        136
3    196-198
4        227
dtype: object
```

---

I then use assign to create a copy of `df` while overwriting the two columns.

```
df.assign(
    ad_StreetNo=df.stack().astype(str).groupby(level=0).apply('-'.join),
    ad_StreetNo2=np.NaN
)

  ad_StreetNo  ad_StreetNo2
0         284           NaN
1          51           NaN
2         136           NaN
3     196-198           NaN
4         227           NaN
```

Comment: same by using `melt` `df.reset_index().melt('index').dropna().groupby('index')['value'].apply(lambda x : '-'.join(x.astype(str)))`